# ruby: matching a pattern against a lazily loaded file

Tags: ruby, regex, file-io, pattern-matching

Is there a way to match a Ruby pattern against the contents of a file, only loading as much of the file as is necessary to match the pattern?

For instance, given the pattern

```
p = /(abc)*/
```

and the file f with contents

```
abcabcdefdef
```

is there a way to match p against the contents of f without reading the last three letters of the file ("def") from disk? Basically, I would like a large file to only be loaded on an as-needed basis while still being able to match a pattern against an arbitrarily long portion of the file.

Comment: What if the last three letters are `abc`? How can it know if it doesn't load the whole file?

Comment: Even if the last three letters were `abc`, as soon as the first `d` is hit the rest of the file can no longer match the pattern since `d` isn't in the pattern.

Comment: Isn't any form of opening the file going to have the entire file in memory anyway?  File.new (or File.open) seems to always open the entire file...

Comment: @jvm_update My mistake, I was assumed he was looking for every match within the file.

Comment: Yes, a file open always happens on a per-file basis. But opening a file and reading it from disk into memory aren't the same thing. The file I have might be many gigabytes long, and I want to be able to match patterns against relatively small parts of it without loading the whole file into memory.

Comment: I gave an answer, but looking over your question again, I'm not sure I really understood it the first time.  Are you looking to concatenate pieces of the file until the regex is matched?

Comment: Short of anything better (which I'm not sure exists in Ruby), your answer would work. I was trying to find something that is compatible with the internal Ruby regex implementation which would sort of treat the file like a string and only examine as much as necessary to match a pattern. I'm not sure this is possible though without reimplementing the entire String interface from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Use an Enumerator to lazy load chunks of the file:

```
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 # adjust to best fit the size of your matching regex
def file_overlapping_chunks filename
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    pos = 0
    while pos < File.size(filename)
      data = File.open(filename,'r') { |f| f.seek(pos); f.read(CHUNK_SIZE) }
      yielder.yield(data)
      pos += (CHUNK_SIZE / 2) # adjust to best fit size of your matching regex
    end
  end
end

chunker = file_overlapping_chunks('my_big_file')
chunker.find { |chunk| chunk =~ /xyz/ }
```

The enumerator allows lazy loading of pieces of the file.  The file chunks are overlapped so that  matching data won't fall on chunk boundaries and get missed.  As I (sloppily) implemented it, the file is not held open, so no open() or close() is necessary to use it. This also isn't the fastest way to do this, but it is easy to use - just call with a file name and use the provided enumerator.